# How to perform arithmetic function in DATE TIME in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have four columns namely-

```
1. C_Date in YYYYMMDD format (varchar(255)) Eg. 20161231
2. C_Time in 4-digit Military format (varchar(255)) Eg. 2143
3. E_Date in YYYYMMDD format (varchar(255)) Eg. 20161230
4. E_Time in 4-digit Military format (varchar(255)) Eg. 1600
```

I want to Calculate the time between E event and C event. How can i perform this computation with a select statement?

Comment: which database?

Comment: Just store dates and times as a single entity

Comment: Its SQL Server database .

Comment: Why are these `varchar(255)`?

Comment: The original format of the columns are varchar(255)

Comment: @Strawberry If I store dates and times in a single entry how I would compute the difference ? Can you please guide me

Comment: See http://rextester.com/QPFCV72778 . Be aware that there are certain limitations with timediff,  it those limitations can be addressed with other functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple to create a date type from the component values:

```
with data as (select '20161231' as c_date, '2143' as c_time)
select 
    convert(
        datetime,
        stuff(stuff(stuff(c_date + ' ' + c_time, 12, 0, ':'), 7, 0, '-'), 5, 0, '-'),
        120
    ) as c_datetime
from data;
```

Use `datediff()` to calculate the time difference. You didn't specify how you wanted the output to look so I won't attempt a guess. There should be a hundred other questions out there with information relevant to your question though.

Also note that I did not append ':00' to the string to represent seconds. It seems to work though I couldn't track down an official document to confirm that. So to be safe you may want to tack that on as well. Arguably there could be a more universal format like ISO 8601 that would be a "better" solution. You get the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

A small matter to convert your strings into a datetime.  Then we use DateDiff() to calculate the differance between the two dates.

```
Declare @YourTable table (C_Date varchar(255),C_Time varchar(255),E_Date varchar(255),E_Time varchar(255))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('20161231','2143','20161230','1600')

;with cte as (
Select * 
      ,CDT = try_convert(DateTime,C_Date+' '+stuff(C_Time,3,0,':'))
      ,EDT = try_convert(DateTime,E_Date+' '+stuff(E_Time,3,0,':'))
 from @YourTable
) 
Select CDT
      ,EDT
      ,Duration  = concat(DateDiff(DD,EDT,CDT),' ',Format(DateAdd(Second,DateDiff(SECOND,EDT,CDT),'1899-12-31'),'HH:mm:ss'))
      ,AsSeconds = DateDiff(SECOND,EDT,CDT)
      ,AsMinutes = DateDiff(MINUTE,EDT,CDT)
 From cte
```

Returns

```
CDT                     EDT                     Duration     AsSeconds   AsMinutes
2016-12-31 21:43:00     2016-12-30 16:00:00     1 05:43:00   106980      1783
```